# Error while running pub deploy: Cannot read link

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to run pub deploy command in my Dart project, but it always ends with this error: "Pub deploy failed, [1] Cannot read link". No more information outputs into console.

I tried to run it in basic Dart browser project (the one with text reversing), but same error occurred again.

Did anyone have same problem? Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
In my case, the Dart project is stored in NTFS hard drive (I share it with Windows OS) and Dart deploy (run from Eclipse) runs on Ubuntu.

Simply move the Dart project to Ubuntu hard drive then things come back to normal.

GS

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with the packages symlinks. If you delete them and run `pub install` it should work again.

Answer (score 0):

According to dart-sdk/lib/io/link.dart:

- On the Windows platform, the link will be created as a Junction
- On other platforms, the posix symlink() call is used to make a symbolic link

On Linux platforms, storing Dart project in NTFS drive causes Pub to fail. Because posix symlink() is used on NTFS partition and doesn't create a valid NTFS junction point.

The solution is to move the project folder to a partition that uses posix symlinks natively, such as one formatted to ext4.